# ESRI Adding js file causes map to disappear

Tags: javascript, dojo, maps, require, esri

I am trying to do the [ESRI JS QuickStart tutorial](https://github.com/Esri/quickstart-map-js).I have found that adding the file [utils.js](https://github.com/Esri/quickstart-map-js/blob/master/js/utils.js),I know just enough js to understand that I need it for the `utils.autoRecenter(map);`

I have copied this file and put it in `~/Desktop/esri/js` while I add it to html using `~/Desktop/esri`.I add it likes this:

```
 require(["esri/map", 
    "js/utils.js",
  "dojo/on", 
  "dojo/dom", 
  "dojo/domReady!"],...
```

It works when I remove this file and the `util.autoRecenter(map);`,but itwont work when I add it.

Comment: Have you checked if the path to the utils.js is absolut correct? Maybe you must just change the path like ../js/utils.js to make it retrievable

Comment: Yes,file is in the same location it was supposed but I found out that I don't have the API key